Effect of heating alkyd enamel paint during drying/curing & maximum acceptable temperature
I will be painting some boat paddles with Solignum Marine Paint (Alkyd enamel) (compliant with new VOC regulations) for a relative. The label lists that it contains mineral spirits and Stoddard Solvent, if that matters. Unfortunately, their website, solignum.ca appears be be in a state of perpetual maintenance. Note: this manufacturer does not appear to be related to the UK-based Solignum, which manufactures wood preservatives.
I'm not very experienced with oil-based paints, so I'm trying to educate myself. I couldn't find any useful info from the manufacturer's website, but have left a voicemail. Regardless, I figured members of this sub-stack could provide some understanding of the chemical processes involved, which would be more valuable in the future.
The label gives the imprecise time between coats of "overnight" at typical temperature and humidity. My research indicates that 16 hours is a general minimum for this type of paint, but 24-48 hours is better. I know the dry/cure time can be reduced by lowering humidity and increasing temperature, but I can't find any information on max temp that is both precise and reliable. E.g. one person said they use a toaster oven at 170°F (77°C) for small parts. But did they damage the paint?
As I understand it, the drying process is when solvents evaportate from the paint and curing is when the paint incorporates atmospheric oxygen and becomes harder. It seems likely that those two stages would have different tolerances.
So, my question...
How much can I increase the temperature after applying a coat to reduce the time required between coats and after the final coat?
I'll be using a radiant heater and should be able to control it fairly precisely.
Additional info: I plan to use the paint thinned. I thinned 500mL of the paint 15% with a thinner that contains Stoddard Solvents, Naptha, and 1,2,4 Trimethylbenzene.
Note: The quality of the finished product is more of a concern than speed. I'm fine with it taking longer, if the end result is better.

What is this product exactly? Solvent info is nowhere as important as polymer itself and catalyst.

@Mithoron I'll add this to the question. The product is Solignum Marine Paint. Unfortunately, their website solignum.ca appears to be in a state of perpetual "scheduled maintenance". P.S. thanks for the info. I've learned something already.

I think nothing beats small scale experiments if applicable.

@Poutnik Yeah, I was considering doing that. Not for this project, but because this question appears to ha e taken up residence in my head. For the paddles, at least for now, I have them in a basement shower enclosure with a dehumidifier (which generates moderate heat). I'm pre-drying the wood now. Once I paint it, I'll be careful to vent enough solvent fumes that I don't blow up the basement when the dehumidifier switches on or off.

Too much heat early in the cycle causes the solvent to bubble out, leaving pockmarks. Also, Valspar recommends a maximum temp of 32 °C (90 °F) https://www.valspar.com/en/products/interior-paints-primers/4000-alkyd-enamel , which might be applicable, or not.
